# What facility was our bus blocked from observing in northern Iran?

Tags: safety, identify-this, iran, military

Recently on a bus trip from Rasht, Iran, to Tehran, Iran, the driver's assistant came down the bus aisle, ordering all the curtains closed on one side, and for a few minutes we were actually forbidden from looking out the windows on that side!

I can only assume he didn't want a hassle with military or something with people seeing ... 'something'? It was a local bus, mostly (we were the only foreigners as far as I know), and was a regularly scheduled normal bus.

We'd just passed Sefid Rud Lake, and heading south, it was on the right side of the bus.  As best I can  tell, we were on or close to [this section of road in google maps](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Rasht,+Gilan,+Iran/@36.6901558,49.4480037,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3ff5620d43f15675:0x41dd40f9931cfbf6!6m1!1e1?hl=en) (I took a GPS reading a short time later).

I'm wondering what was on that section of the road that we weren't allowed to see?  I asked my Iranian friends, but they didn't know either.  Just a military base or something else?

Comment: Maybe the mosque.

Comment: Saw plenty of mosques, no problems seeing those :/

Comment: Given that - judging from the answer so far - this question might be drawing attention to the location of a nuclear research centre, I do hope you waited until *after* you'd left Iran before posting this `:-)`

Comment: Iran is busy constructing missile bases in that area.

Comment: @user568458 6 countries ago ;)

Comment: could you tell us how you felt forbidden to look out?? and how long it took before you opened the curtains again? and what time of day it was?

Comment: @Bludream how I felt? Curious, more than anything.  About 3-5 minutes. Roughly 2-3pm.

Comment: It's totally, weird! I've never experienced that in my country and I'm wondering how wise it is to put something not for seen beside a road!!

Comment: Perhaps the Lowshan Power Plant: https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Rasht,+Gilan,+Iran/@36.6581569,49.4569693,902m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x3ff5620d43f15675:0x41dd40f9931cfbf6!6m1!1e1?hl=en

Comment: You can't just hide a suspected nuclear site by closing the curtains. Especially given that that's a public road anyone has access to (including IAEA inspectors). As an Iranian I'd say it's much more probable that the driver wanted to spread this gossip than there being any nuclear activity.

Comment: Did your bus had a stop there or shortly after?

Comment: Maybe an hour after, but no, not there.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [this map from the Nuclear Threat Initiative](https://web.archive.org/web/20090206090243/http://nti.org/e_research/profiles_pdfs/Iran/iran_nuclear_sites.pdf) (2006), your GPS reading at the western bend of the road between Rasht and Qazvin corresponds almost perfectly to "**Mo-Allem Kalayeh: Suspected nuclear research center**".

However!  [This (ancient) page](http://fas.org/nuke/guide/iran/facility/moallem_kalaych.htm) gives the site's coordinates as [36°26'05"N 50°29'53"E](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/36%C2%B026'05.0%22N+50%C2%B029'53.0%22E/@36.4347222,50.4980556,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en), which is a) a lot closer to where [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moallem_Kalayeh) thinks Moallem Kalayeh (معلم كلايه‎) is located, and b) nowhere near where you went.  That said, the FAS site seems to be simply matching names to towns, so it's by no means clear which of the two is wrong...